# Is it possible to pass in a DOM7 Element to React.hydrate() after it's rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am trying to append a React component in Swiper JS by using the `appendSlide()` function. Unfortunately, `appendSlide()` [takes in raw HTML as its argument](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#methods-and-properties).

[Code Sandbox demo of my current problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-hypatia-z0ukm?file=/src/App.js).

I have successfully appended a **static** slide by doing `swiper.appendSlide(renderToString(<MyComponent />))`. The issue is that there are no event listeners attached. `swiper.$el[0]` gets me the [DOM7 Element of the Swiper instance](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#methods-and-properties), and I thought I could pass that in to a `React.hydrate()` call to initialize the event listeners, but that threw an error: `Target container is not a DOM node`.

On a separate note as well, the following error is thrown in my console due to the `renderToString` call, even though this code is running on the client side:

```
Warning: useLayoutEffect does nothing on the server, because its effect cannot be encoded into the server renderer's output 
format. This will lead to a mismatch between the initial, non-hydrated UI and the intended UI. To avoid this, useLayoutEffect 
should only be used in components that render exclusively on the client.
```

How should I be adding all necessary event listeners to this added component?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not just use React to append the slides? You just need to update the render to contain the new slides when the "Add Slides" button is clicked. As a quick example: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-minsky-h07mv This uses an array to track the number of slides. Usually the array would hold an object with info to be passed as props to each slide but in the example it is only being used for the count. The button updates the array (in state) which causes a component rerender, the render maps all array entries out as slides.

Comment: @JacobSmit Thanks for the response, but there is a problem with this solution. What I require is that I can push to the end of this array and remove an element at any arbitrary index in the array. The problem is that if you attempt to remove an element, what happens is that the other slides *lose their state*, their states get reset to the default state. You can check it out here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/swiper-remove-slides-w4gy3?codemirror=1. Add a slide, change the state in that slide, delete the slide at index 0. The state of the slide at index 1 is reset.

Comment: This is why I was hoping to find a solution to append the slide using the Swiper API because removing a slide using the remove slide method bundled with Swiper works without causing a loss of state.

Comment: I found a solution to this here as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67555505/deleting-a-slide-in-swiperjs-mapped-with-an-array-without-the-state-resetting/67592279#67592279. This question is not as valid anymore since dealing with the array is the correct way to do it, without using the Swiper append or remove slide functions.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate since OP indicated they found the answer and posted the answer in the question they linked.